# Query logic issue: Using parameters and variables in a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to combine 2 different select statements (each are being put into 2 variables) and then using 2 parameters to show my results, but I'm not 100% confident with my logic.

I'm using 2 tables (Salaries and Department)

I first created the procedure with the 2 parameters:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DepartmentPercentage
(
    @Dept VARCHAR(20)
    @DeptPercent int OUTPUT
)
```

Then I declared and set my 2 variables, using an inner join in one of them to connect the Salaries and Department tables:

```
AS
DECLARE @Sal int
DECLARE @DeptRate int
SET @Sal = (SELECT SUM(AN_RATE) FROM Salaries) --Total Annual Rate for the entire table
SET @DeptRate = (SELECT SUM(S.AN_RATE) -- Calculates the Total Annual Rate for a given Department
    FROM Salaries as S
    INNER JOIN Department as D
    ON D.DEPT_ID = S.DEPT_ID
    WHERE DESCRIPTION = @Dept)
```

Then I put my out parameter to equal a division between the 2 declared variables:

```
@DeptPercent = (@DeptRate/@Sal)
```

My execution statement:

```
EXEC DepartmentPercentage @Dept = 'Fire Department', @DeptPercent;
```

Any help with my logic would be much appreciated. I don't know too much about using multiple parameters and variables in a single query.

Comment: Don't forget to let us know if the answer has resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you Close to the results you want without the need for all the parameters and variables:

```
SELECT SUM(S.AN_RATE) AS total,   
       SUM(CASE DESCRIPTION WHEN @Dept THEN S.AN_RATE ELSE 0 END) AS dept,
       SUM(CASE DESCRIPTION WHEN @Dept THEN S.AN_RATE ELSE 0 END) / SUM(S.AN_RATE) AS deptPercent
FROM Salaries as S
INNER JOIN Department as D
    ON D.DEPT_ID = S.DEPT_ID
```

I know you probably only want the last column but thought the other 2 might help other people.  If I get chance in the morning I'll setup a SQLfiddle with test data.

SQLFiddle seems to be having some problems at the minute so here is a worked example:

```
--Test Data Setup
DECLARE @Salaries AS TABLE (SAL_ID int, DEPT_ID int, AN_RATE decimal(7,2))
DECLARE @Department AS TABLE (DEPT_ID int, DEPT_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @Department VALUES (1,  'Fire Department')
INSERT INTO @Department VALUES (2,  'Earth Department')
INSERT INTO @Department VALUES (3,  'Wind Department')

INSERT INTO @Salaries VALUES (1, 1, 10000.00)
INSERT INTO @Salaries VALUES (2, 1, 15000.00)
INSERT INTO @Salaries VALUES (3, 1, 20000.00)

INSERT INTO @Salaries VALUES (4, 3, 25000.00)

INSERT INTO @Salaries VALUES (5, 2, 22000.00)

INSERT INTO @Salaries VALUES (6, 2, 21000.00)

--Parameter
DECLARE @Dept VARCHAR(20)
SET @Dept = 'Fire Department'

--Query
SELECT SUM(S.AN_RATE) AS total,   
       SUM(CASE DEPT_DESCRIPTION WHEN @Dept THEN S.AN_RATE ELSE 0 END) AS dept,
       SUM(CASE DEPT_DESCRIPTION WHEN @Dept THEN S.AN_RATE ELSE 0 END) / SUM(S.AN_RATE) * 100 AS deptPercent
FROM @Salaries as S
INNER JOIN @Department as D
    ON D.DEPT_ID = S.DEPT_ID
```